# How do you upload a photo in Flex 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

In Flex 3 how to upload a photo ssing Browse and Upload option?

In Flex 4 there is an option like:

```
<net:FileReference id="fileReference"
                       select="fileReference_select(event);"
                       complete="fileReference_complete(event);" />
```

But in Flex 3 there is no `<net>` tag.

**EDIT:**

This is my Button click handler code

```
protected function uploadProfileImage(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            
            var fileRef:FileReference= new FileReference();
            browseButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick);
            
            function onButtonClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
                fileRef.browse([new FileFilter("Images", "*.jpg;*.gif;*.png")]);
                fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected);
                Alert.show("0")
            }
            
            function onFileSelected(e:Event):void {
                fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
                //fileRef.load();
                Alert.show("1");
            }
            
            function onFileLoaded(e:Event):void {
                var loader:Loader = new Loader();
                loader.loadBytes(e.target.data);
                //addChild(loader);
                profileImage.data = loader.content;
                profileImage.width = loader.width;
                profileImage.height = loader.height;
                this.height = profileImage.height;
                this.width = profileImage.width;
                this.visible = true;
                Alert.show("2");

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `<net>` tag in Flex 4 either. The `net` part in `<net:FileReference...` is an xml namespace. There are a bunch defined at the top of your application's MXML file. Here's a sample from a Flash-based Flex 4 app:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
```

The `xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"` is just mapping all the Spark components to the `s` namespace which allows you to reference Spark components like Button in MXML like this:

```
<s:Button label="My Button"/>
```

In the case of Spark Adobe has provided a manifest file that maps the fully qualified Spark packages to the familiar MXML names ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453919/how-can-i-make-flashbuilder-use-a-custom-namespace-prefix) question has an example of such a file). You can also map AS3 package names to an xml namespace.

[FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) is in the `flash.net` package. You can bind that package to the `net` namespace by adding the following to the root tag in your MXML file:

```
xmlns:net="flash.net.*"
```

Once you do that you can reference classes in the `flash.net` package in MXML by prefixing them with "net" ala `<net:FileReference...`.

Of course, `FileReference` doesn't inherit `UIComponent` so you won't be able to add it directly to your application. So that's probably not what is happening in your case.

Without seeing more than what you've posted I suspect that the `FileReference` in your question is a custom component that has it's package bound to the `net` xmlns.

Can you post the complete MXML document that has the `<net:FileReference...` tag in it?

### EDIT

Using the code you added, in your script block have this:

```
var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();

function onButtonClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    fileRef.browse([new FileFilter("Images", "*.jpg;*.gif;*.png")]);
    fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected);
    fileRef.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, onFileCanceled);
}

function onFileSelected(e:Event):void {
    fileRef.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected);
    fileRef.removeEventListener(Event.CANCEL, onFileCanceled);

    fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
    fileRef.load();
}

function onFileCanceled(e:Event):void {
    fileRef.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected);
    fileRef.removeEventListener(Event.CANCEL, onFileCanceled);
}

function onFileLoaded(e:Event):void {
    fileRef.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.loadBytes(e.target.data);
    profileImage.data = loader.content;
    profileImage.width = loader.width;
    profileImage.height = loader.height;
    profileImage.visible = true;
}
```

Then in your MXML have something like:

```
<mx:Button
    label="Click to Load Profile Image"
    click="onButtonClick(event)"/>

<mx:Image
    id="profileImage"
    visible="false"/>
```

### EDIT 2

If you are having problems with calling `load()` on `FileReference` make sure you are targeting the correct Flash Player. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839259/flash-builder-4-6-not-compiling-for-flash-player-10-2/8841549#8841549) explains how to do that in Flash Builder. IIRC, Flex 3 projects target Flash Player 9 be default.

Comment: give me one example image Upload Using Flex 3

Comment: Thank you for your replay... In above code show there is no load() method in FileReference ...Please help me ...

Comment: Which version of Flash Player are you using? [load()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#load()) was adding in FP10.

Comment: Then load() is definitely available to you. Is the app not compiling? Throwing an error? What's going wrong?

Comment: Error:
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method load through a reference with static type flash.net:FileReference.

Comment: If you run the following in your app what version does it say: `Alert.show("Flash Player Version: " + flash.system.Capabilities.version);`

Comment: Flash Player Version: WIN 11,6,602,146

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23131/discussion-between-narasimham-k-and-noobsarepeople2)